# How can I get a visual representation of my solution's dependency chain and member hooks?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, dependencies, projects-and-solutions

I've been tasked with researching some .NET code that isn't mine. It's a little hard to figure out because there are so many hooks in different areas. In other words, everything seems to be very highly coupled.

I'd like to be able to do the following:

1. Very easily see a hierarchical (tree) view of projects and their direct dependencies (not just references)
2. Be able to easily (visually) trace specific API hooks back from a dependent class to it's dependency. For example: If ProjectA.ClassA.Method1() has a call to ProjectB.ClassB.Method2() within the method, I want to be able to see it

And hey, maybe visually isn't the best way to go. But it seems to always work better for me that way. I'll take any and all suggestions of course.

Answer (score 3):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) is awesome for this sort of thing. It's a little pricey, but you can get quite far with the free trial.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the VSTS Architecture Explorer (included in Architecture Edition or Team Suite). Also the [Resharper 5 (beta)](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/beta/beta.html) Code Inspector offers some functionality for this.

If you need the feature only temporary, you can try the [Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=457bab91-5eb2-4b36-b0f4-d6f34683c62a&displaylang=en). It's freely available and includes the Architecture Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

[Structure101](http://headwaysoftware.com) gives you this in both graphical and [list/treeview](http://www.headwaysoftware.com/products/structure101/client/impact-analysis.php) formats. It's commercial but not expensive, and you can abuse the trial license if it's a quick job.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the Phil answer on graphs generated by NDepend, the tool comes with both a dependency graph and a dependency matrix and integrates in VS. The graph and matrix can be generated from .NET assemblies and they are interactive.

You can [download and use the free trial edition](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependDownload.aspx) for a while and make your own opinion.

[More on NDepend Dependency Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx)
[image]

[More on NDepend Dependency Matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx):
[image]

*Disclaimer: I am part of the tool team*